# Wordpress, Divi, Image replace on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Looking for a code I can plug in
Using images to make a giant interactive button

I'm working with the divi code module in word press. I want to be able to have an image swap with another image on mouse over. Also change back when mouse off all with a reasonably fast fade. (I will plug in the image Urls ).

I also want the image to link to a url (I will add this, again just say where in the code i.e 
|your url here|).

For mobile or devices with touch screen I would like the First image to change to the second on taping the image, then redirecting to the same url

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Watch my codepen: http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/wzYZAP

```
background: url('http://www.hutui6.com/data/out/102/66775709-image-wallpapers.jpg');
```

I set a background image in the css, which changes on hover...

On mobile devices hover effects are automatically appearing when tapping, so thats the same.

Comment: Thanks, tried plugging that in, just came up as text. I think doing it this wa it works but im missing part of the code

Comment: <a class="ds-hover-1" href="(URL LINK)"><img src="(URL IMAGE)"></a>

Comment: Sorry I don't know a lot about code, is this a different code language?

Comment: just go to my link... self-explaining over there

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit more digging, here is how to do it. With HTML

```
    <a class="ds-hover-1" href="(LINK URL)"><img src="(NORMAL IMAGE URL)"onmouseover="this.src='(OVERLAY IMAGE URL)'" onmouseout="this.src='(NORMAL IMAGE URL)'"></a>
```

P.S My First line of Html ever written haha what a scrub
Now Investigating how to do a fade